# Regular expression with condition

Tags: python, regex

I have been working on the python code to extract document Ids from text documents where IDs can be at the random line in the text using regex.

This document ID is comprised of four letters followed by a hyphen, followed by three numbers and optionally ending in a letter. For example, each of the following is valid document IDs:

1. ABCD-123
2. ABCD-123V
3. XKCD-999
4. COMP-200

I have tried following regular expression for finding all ids:

```
re = re.findall(r"([A-Z]{4})(-)([0-9]{3})([A-Z]{0,1})", text.read())
```

These expressions work correctly but I have a problem when Ids are connected to words like:

`XKCD-999James`

The regular expression should return `XKCD-999` but it is returning `XKCD-999J` which is incorrect.

What changes should I do in RE to get the correct?

Comment: What is your expected output for `ABCD-123V`? Is it `ABCD-123V` or Just `ABCD-123`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead assertion to ignore patterns that have trailing letters:

```
exp = re.findall(r"([A-Z]{4})(-)([0-9]{3})([A-Z](?![A-Za-z]))?", text.read())
#                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are using word characters, you can optionally match a char A-Z followed by a word boundary.

```
\b[A-Z]{4}-[0-9]{3}(?:[A-Z]\b)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ioIWRB/1)

Note that using re.findall will return the captured groups, so if you want to return just the whole match, you can omit the groups.

With the capture groups, the pattern can be:

```
\b([A-Z]{4})(-)([0-9]{3}(?:[A-Z]\b)?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BSzka5/1)

Answer (score 1):

How about you use a boundary operation `\b` ?

`[A-Z]{4}-\d{3}(?:[A-Z]\b)?`

Regex101 Sample - https://regex101.com/r/DhC5Vd/4

```
text = "XKCD-999James"
exp = re.findall(r"[A-Z]{4}-\d{3}(?:[A-Z]\b)?", text)
#OUTPUT: ['XKCD-999']
```